# Errors during group by on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Can you please advise on the below, I'm a bit stuck.

So, dataframe3 has the columns, 'domain' and 'size'. My script cleans up the domain and adds a new column called 'newdomain2'

I add the column below & view the dataframe & it looks correct.

So then, df4 needs to be an aggregated version of df3 (grouped by domain + sum(size), but when I try the below, I get this error:

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

I should note, that if I use 'domain' rather than 'cleandomain2' in the same script, it works without error.

Are you able to help me understand why this might be?

```
 df3['newdomain2']=cleandomain
 #show df3
 df3

 df4 = df3.groupby(['newdomain2'])[['size']].sum()
```

**Here is the script I use to generate the new column values & add the values to the dataframe**

```
for x in index:
     #if it ends with a number, it's an IP
     if str(x[len(x)-1]).isnumeric():
         cleandomain.append(str(x[0])+'.'+str(x[1])+'.*.*')
     #if its in the CDN list, take a subdomain as well
     elif str(x[len(x)-2]).rstrip() in cdns:
         cleandomain.append(str(x[len(x)-3])+'.'+str(x[len(x)-2])+'.'+str(x[len(x)-1]))
     elif str(x[len(x)-3]).rstrip() in cdns:
         cleandomain.append(str(x[len(x)-4])+'.'+str(x[len(x)-3])+'.'+str(x[len(x)-2])+'.'+ str(x[len(x)-1]))
    #if its in the TLD list, do this
     elif str(x[len(x)-2]).rstrip()+'.'+ str(x[len(x)-1]).rstrip() in tld:
         cleandomain.append(str(x[len(x)-3])+'.'+str(x[len(x)-2])+'.'+ str(x[len(x)-1]))
     elif str(x[len(x)-1]) in tld:
         cleandomain.append(str(x[len(x)-2])+'.'+ str(x[len(x)-1]))
    #if its not in the TLD list, do this
     else:
         cleandomain.append(x)
 #add column do df3
 df3['newdomain2']=cleandomain
```

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/doc/cheatsheet/Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf
Hope this helps

Comment: how does `df3` look like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly put a list into a dataframe column,

```
df3['your_col'] = pd.Series(your_list).values
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - even doing this, I get the same error, any ideas?